# Can't install "Patch"

Tags: installation, patch

I'm trying to apply a patch to a package and I don't seem to have patch installed, but when I type 
`sudo apt-get install patch` it gives me this message:

Ubuntu 11.10 *Oneiric Ocelot* - Release amd64 (20111012)'
in the drive `/cdrom/` and press enter

How can I install it? Cuz I actually have the installation cd on my drive, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove cdrom from sources.list either manualy or with software-properties-gtk program. Just launch it and uncheck corresponding checkboxes.

Comment: Thanx. Problem solved :D

Comment: @FrancoAlbornoz: If this solves your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Please share what you did to solve the issue.